# Determine if a computer is connected to the internet

Tags: windows, winsock

I need to determine in a c++ program whether a Windows computer connected to internet. For Vista and above, there is IsInternetConnected() function, it works as expected. For XP, it should be possible by obtaining _NLA_BLOB by WSALookupServiceNext() as described in
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms700657(v=vs.85).aspx .

However, when running on Windows 7, it indeed returns some blobs of type NLA_CONNECTIVITY (for physical and vmware virtual NICs), some with NLA_INTERNET_YES and some with NLA_INTERNET_NO. When I run it on Windows XP, there are no such blobs at all. Should it work this way on XP and I'm doing something wrong, or I should look for some other approach?
I'd prefer not to ping some known site unless it's the only way to get it done.

p.s. - ultimately we decided to just ping, at least on XP.

Comment: The [`InternetGetConnectedState`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384702.aspx) function should work fine on XP. There are better ways of obtaining this information in later versions of Windows, but using the same function on all versions is probably sufficient if your requirements are simple.

Comment: Unfortunately, it returns the same value 0x12 on 'normal' network and in host-only private network.